# Remove the Icon Double-click close feature in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to keep the icon on my program, but would like to remove the double-click close
feature. Is there any way of doing this?

I have not found anything about this on google tho.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense unless you *also* want to disable the system menu and the window's Close button.  Intentionally removing a standard window gadget is very unwise, nothing that pretty about a user banging away at the mouse and not having any idea why a standard operation doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   Size iconSize = new Size(32,32);
   Rectangle R = new Rectangle(this.Location, iconSize);
   if (R.Contains(Cursor.Position) && e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing) 
       e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options.  The side effect is that the window's top right X (close button) is disabled on Windows 8.  I believe on windows XP it is removed completely.

Option 1: Override the Form's OnHandleCreated:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetMenuItemCount(IntPtr hMenu);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool RemoveMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int uPosition, uint uFlags);

protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    const uint MF_BYPOSITION = 0x00000400;
    IntPtr hMenu = GetSystemMenu(this.Handle, false);
    int n = GetMenuItemCount(hMenu);
    RemoveMenu(hMenu, n-1, MF_BYPOSITION); // remove last (always close?)
}
```

Option 2: override the Form's CreateParams.  The advantage of this one is that it does the work of also removing the separator.

```
    // this code will hide the close X button, since there is no CloseBox Form property
protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
    get {
        const int CS_NOCLOSE = 0x0200;
        CreateParams param = base.CreateParams;
        param.ClassStyle = param.ClassStyle | CS_NOCLOSE;
        return param;
    }
}
```